# Change the color of a button while clicking on it flask js html

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button ON/OFF, when I click on it to put it ON I want the button to become green and when I click on it to put it OFF I want the button to become red.

I am using Flask with Python HTML Javascript

Here is my line for the button in `html`:

```
<input onclick="changeColor()" type="submit" name="drive_state" id="onoffbutton" value={{drive_state}}>
```

The value `{{drive_state}}` is coded in the python file. The values of this button are either "On" or "Off".

So, I created this `javascript file`:

```
function changeColor() {
    if (document.getElementById("onoffbutton").value == 'On') {
        document.getElementById("onoffbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#3DCE65';
    }else {
        document.getElementById("onoffbutton").style.backgroundColor = '#CF1823';
    }    
}
```

But whenever I am clicking on this ON/OFF button, I receive the following error: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css button and create event inside button

```css
.mystyle {
 background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>



<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">ON/OFF</button>



<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("button");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code and the button is always green. It has to turn red with the button is off and green when the button is on.

Comment: The problem is in your function remove all styling from your function and refer to the style with id. Did you run my snippet code? You need to toggle style.

Comment: I think it is not working because there is a conflict between python and javascript. If I remove the dependency between the button and some python script and leave only javascript, it's working.

Comment: Good luck Camille, if you do not get right place a bounty on question or repost, sorry i will upvote your last comment to mark it as important  ;-)